# FileUpload to bitmap to base64String

Tags: c#

In my ASP.NET form I have a file upload control where I am letting users upload image files, converting it into base64String to store it in the database.

I am using following code to do so,

```
     if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
            {
                var img = new Bitmap(FileUploadControl.FileContent);
                if (img.Height > 133 || img.Width > 133)
                {
                    img = ResizeImage(img, 132, 132);
                }

                u.Photo = ImageToBase64String(img);
            }

    private static string ImageToBase64String(Bitmap img)
    {
        var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
        var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
        return base64String;
    }

    private static Bitmap ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int width, int height)
    {
        var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

        destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
        {
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
            {
                wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
            }
        }

        return destImage;
    }
```

**Now I am worried about followings,**

- Overall code review
- Creating two Bitmap classes they are disposable but am not sure if I can dispose them at all
- I seem to be doing unnecessary conversion because I don't have enough knowledge.

**Goal**

- Convert uploaded images to 132 x 132 if they are over it and save them as base64String.

Comment: Do you have to convert the bitmap data to Base64? You can store it in the database in binary form, which will require less storage space, and which will avoid a cpu bound conversion to base 64 for a huge data like a bitmap

Answer (score 5):

In `ImageToBase64String()` you do not dispose your stream. GC will do it but server-side is never never a good idea to postpone resource deallocation:

```
static string ImageToBase64String(Bitmap img)
{
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Note that if you use this feature often you may reduce memory pressure reusing same buffer, you may implement an [`ObjectPool<MemoryStream>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458671(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

You create a new bitmap just for resizing then yes, it has to be disposed too:

```
private static string ResizeAndConvertToBase64(Stream stream)
{
    using (var image = new Bitmap(FileUploadControl.FileContent))
    {
        if (IsTooBig(image))
        {
            using (var scaledImage = ScaleDownImage(image))
            {
                return ImageToBase64String(scaledImage);
            }
        }

        return ImageToBase64String(image);
    }
}

private static bool IsTooBig(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    return bitmap.Width > MaximumWidth || bitmap.Height > MaximumHeight;
}
```

Note I also moved magic numbers from code to constants `MaximumWidth` and `MaximumHeight`. Now you still have to deal with `ScaleDownImage()`. First of all you may want to keep image aspect ratio then I'd first move this calculation to another separate function (I dropped settings unused for image drawing):

```
private static Bitmap ScaleDownImage(Bitmap image)
{
    var newSize = ResolveScaledDownImageSize(image);
    var scaled = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(scaled))
    {
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, newSize));
    }

    return scaled;
}
```

There is also a built-in method to re-scale images, you should check if it satisfy your needing, in this case drop `ScaleDownImage()` and change `ResizeAndConvertToBase64()` as follow:

```
private static string ResizeAndConvertToBase64(Stream stream)
{
    using (var image = new Bitmap(FileUploadControl.FileContent))
    {
        if (IsTooBig(image))
        {
            using (var scaledImage = new Bitmap(image, ResolveScaledDownImageSize(image)))
            {
                return ImageToBase64String(scaledImage);
            }
        }

        return ImageToBase64String(image);
    }
}
```

In general don't forget to always call `Dispose()` for classes which implement `IDisposable` and whenever possible use `using` statement to simplify that code.

Now only `ResolveScaledDownImageSize()` function is empty. If you do not need to keep aspect ratio you may simply:

```
private static ResolveScaledDownImageSize(Bitmap image)
{
    return new Size(
        Math.Min(MaximumWidth, image.Width),
        Math.Min(MaximumHeight, image.Height));
}
```

To keep aspect ratio you may keep width or height (according to which one is bigger than required), you can use *one* of these to perform calculation:

\$height_{new} = \frac{height}{width} width_{new}\$

*or*

\$width_{new} = \frac{width}{height} height_{new}\$